# Quartz scheduler behaves inconsistently

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduling, job-scheduling

I have a simple Job class with message and a setter that executes for 5 seconds. This job class is annotated by @DisallowConcurrentExecution so that it can't be executed multiple times at once.

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class LongJob implements Job {

    private String message = "Default";
    private int sleepTime = 1000;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setSleepTime(int sleepTime) {
        this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
    }

    public LongJob() {
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                System.out.println(new Date().toString() + " - " + count + ": " + message);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LongJob.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

In my main method I try to run this class 6 times, every time with different message.

```
        SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
        sched.start();

        String name = "LongJob2X";
        JobDetail job = newJob(LongJob.class)
                .withIdentity(name, "group1")
                .storeDurably()
                .requestRecovery(true)
                .build();

        sched.addJob(job, true);

        JobDataMap data = new JobDataMap();
        data.put("message", "Prvy");

        JobDataMap data2 = new JobDataMap();
        data2.put("message", "Druhy");

        JobDataMap data3= new JobDataMap();
        data.put("message", "3");

        JobDataMap data4 = new JobDataMap();
        data.put("message", "stvrty");

        JobDataMap data5 = new JobDataMap();
        data.put("message", "5");

        JobDataMap data6 = new JobDataMap();
        data.put("message", "xsiesty6");

        sched.triggerJob(job.getKey(), data);
        sched.triggerJob(job.getKey(), data2);
        sched.triggerJob(job.getKey(), data3);
        sched.triggerJob(job.getKey(), data4);
        sched.triggerJob(job.getKey(), data5);
        sched.triggerJob(job.getKey(), data6);
```

What confuses me is the output. Although the code is the same for each trigger, sometimes the setter for message isn't called, hence this output:

```
Thu Jan 22 23:32:09 CET 2015 - 0: xsiesty6
Thu Jan 22 23:32:10 CET 2015 - 1: xsiesty6
Thu Jan 22 23:32:11 CET 2015 - 2: xsiesty6
Thu Jan 22 23:32:12 CET 2015 - 3: xsiesty6
Thu Jan 22 23:32:13 CET 2015 - 4: xsiesty6
Thu Jan 22 23:32:14 CET 2015 - 0: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:15 CET 2015 - 1: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:16 CET 2015 - 2: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:17 CET 2015 - 3: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:18 CET 2015 - 4: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:19 CET 2015 - 0: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:20 CET 2015 - 1: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:21 CET 2015 - 2: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:22 CET 2015 - 3: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:23 CET 2015 - 4: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:24 CET 2015 - 0: Druhy
Thu Jan 22 23:32:25 CET 2015 - 1: Druhy
Thu Jan 22 23:32:26 CET 2015 - 2: Druhy
Thu Jan 22 23:32:27 CET 2015 - 3: Druhy
Thu Jan 22 23:32:28 CET 2015 - 4: Druhy
Thu Jan 22 23:32:30 CET 2015 - 0: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:31 CET 2015 - 1: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:32 CET 2015 - 2: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:33 CET 2015 - 3: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:34 CET 2015 - 4: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:35 CET 2015 - 0: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:36 CET 2015 - 1: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:37 CET 2015 - 2: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:38 CET 2015 - 3: Default
Thu Jan 22 23:32:39 CET 2015 - 4: Default
```

Every run I've tried was only the second and the last message set. Is there a limit for how many JobDataMaps can be stored at one time? Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

One last note: I am using JDBC JobStore like this:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, you are putting your message on the same `data` almost every time, instead of having `data.put(...)`, `data2.put(...)`,  `data3.put(...)`, ...

```
    JobDataMap data = new JobDataMap();
    data.put("message", "Prvy"); //Correct

    JobDataMap data2 = new JobDataMap();
    data2.put("message", "Druhy");// Correct

    JobDataMap data3= new JobDataMap();
    data.put("message", "3");// Here not data3 but data

    JobDataMap data4 = new JobDataMap();
    data.put("message", "stvrty");// Here not data4 but data

    JobDataMap data5 = new JobDataMap();
    data.put("message", "5"); // Here not data5 but data

    JobDataMap data6 = new JobDataMap();
    data.put("message", "xsiesty6");  // Here not data6 but data
```

Comment: You're right, I hate when this happens :). I've been looking at the code for 10 minutes, guess it's a little bit too late for programming now :).